# Need to Identify This Bug

Tags: species-identification

When I woke up this morning I found 10 or more of these tiny little red and brown bug on the window to above the kitchen sink. They must be attracted to the light as the sun was just rising. I killed as many as I could but they are very small and hard to see. They are mostly bright red. Have 6 legs and antenna. [image]

Does anyone know what they are? Are they dangerous?

Thank you,

Hersh

Comment: Please add some information on the location where these bugs where found.

Comment: Specifically where in the world you are based - nearby major city or state will help.

Comment: This question is more about zoology than biology.

Comment: Can you explain your need to identify it? (what exactly is your need? do you need species, genus, family?) If you cannot explain your need here, please adjust your title to be more informative/specific about your post.

Comment: (these are aphids, btw... but genus and species is not obvious and would need geography to have a chance to identify)

Comment: Hello all, I am in Swedesboro, NJ USA. I want to know what the bugs are to know how to deal with them in my house.

Answer (score 2):

This is an [aphid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphid), so it could be at most dangerous if you were a plant. ;)
You can recognize them by a soft, often colorful body, relatively long antennas and legs and the so-called [cornicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornicle).

[image: aphid cornicle]